# Search button in Laravel Filament table filter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

Hello everything is fine? I need help. I searched a lot, and so far I haven't found it. I'm using filament in a large project using MongoDB, and I'm having a problem.
I have a text index, which can bring me the information quickly if I send what I want at once. For example, I have a "cod" field that, if I send the information I want, it returns instantly, but if I type it, each time the filament tries to search based on the character typed, demanding a lot from the server. Given this, could anyone help me with a way so that I can insert a button in the filter, where the table will only be filtered when it is clicked?

My filter code:

```
Filter::make('filter')
                ->form([
                    Grid::make(4)
                        ->schema([
                            Select::make('DocumentType')
                                ->options([
                                    'CONTRATO' => 'CONTRATO',
                                    'DOCUMENTO' => 'DOCUMENTO',
                                ])->label('Tipo de Digitalização')
                                ->reactive()
                                ->hidden(function (callable $get){
                                    return $get('FullName') || $get('Rg') || $get('Cpf') || $get('Codigo') || $get('Sequencial') || $get('date_init') || $get('date_end');
                                }),
                            
                            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('FullName')
                                ->label('Nome')
                                ->reactive()
                                ->hidden(function (callable $get){
                                    return $get('Cpf') || $get('Rg') || $get('DocumentType') || $get('Codigo') || $get('Sequencial') || $get('date_init') || $get('date_end');
                                }),

                            Forms\Components\DateTimePicker::make('date_init')
                                ->label('Digitalizado a partir de')
                                ->reactive()
                                ->hidden(function (callable $get){
                                    return $get('FullName') || $get('Rg') || $get('DocumentType') || $get('Codigo') || $get('Sequencial') || $get('Cpf');
                                }),

                            Forms\Components\DateTimePicker::make('date_end')
                                ->label('Digitalizado até')
                                ->reactive()
                                ->hidden(function (callable $get){
                                    return $get('FullName') || $get('Rg') || $get('DocumentType') || $get('Codigo') || $get('Sequencial') || $get('Cpf');
                                }),
                    ]),
                    Grid::make(4)
                        ->schema([                           
                            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('Cpf')
                                ->label('CPF')
                                ->reactive()
                                ->hidden(function (callable $get){
                                    return $get('FullName') || $get('Rg') || $get('DocumentType') || $get('Codigo') || $get('Sequencial') || $get('date_init') || $get('date_end');
                                }),

                            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('Rg')
                                ->label('RG')
                                ->reactive()
                                ->hidden(function (callable $get){
                                    return $get('FullName') || $get('Cpf') || $get('DocumentType') || $get('Codigo') || $get('Sequencial') || $get('date_init') || $get('date_end');
                                }),

                            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('Codigo')
                                ->label('Código')
                                ->reactive()
                                ->hidden(function (callable $get){
                                    return $get('FullName') || $get('Rg') || $get('DocumentType') || $get('Cpf') || $get('Sequencial') || $get('date_init') || $get('date_end');
                                }),

                            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('Sequencial')
                                ->label('Sequencial')
                                ->reactive()
                                ->hintColor('primary')
                                ->hidden(function (callable $get){
                                    return $get('FullName') || $get('Rg') || $get('DocumentType') || $get('Codigo') || $get('Cpf') || $get('date_init') || $get('date_end');
                                }),
                        ]),
                ])->query(function (Builder $query, array $data): Builder {
                    return $query
                        ->when(
                            $data['DocumentType'],
                            fn (Builder $query, $value): Builder => $query->where('DocumentType', '=', $value),
                        )->when(
                            $data['FullName'],
                            fn (Builder $query, $value): Builder => $query->whereRaw(array('$text'=>array('$search'=> "\"" . $value . "\"")))
                        )->when(
                            $data['Codigo'],
                            fn (Builder $query, $value): Builder => $query->whereRaw(array('$text'=>array('$search'=> "\"" . $value . "\"")))
                        )->when(
                            $data['Rg'],
                            fn (Builder $query, $value): Builder => $query->whereRaw(array('$text'=>array('$search'=> "\"" . $value . "\"")))
                        )->when(
                            $data['Sequencial'],
                            fn (Builder $query, $value): Builder => $query->whereRaw(array('$text'=>array('$search'=> "\"" . $value . "\"")))
                        )->when(
                            $data['Cpf'],
                            fn (Builder $query, $value): Builder => $query->whereRaw(array('$text'=>array('$search'=> "\"" . $value . "\"")))
                        )
                        ->when(
                            $data['date_init'],
                            fn (Builder $query, $value): Builder => $query->where('created_at', '>=',new DateTime($value))
                        )->when(
                            $data['date_end'],
                            fn (Builder $query, $value): Builder => $query->where('created_at', '<=',new DateTime($value))
                        );
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `->reactive()` from your form inputs if you don’t want them to trigger the filter immediately upon change. You need to add a custom button that the user will click to apply the filters:

```
Filter::make('filter')
    ->form([
        // ... 

        Button::make('Apply Filters')
            ->action(function (array $data) {
                // at here apply the filter to your query.
                // and you can store the $data in the session or in some other temporary state.
            }),
    ])
    // ...
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response.
So, I tried to use your alternative, but I got an error. Imports do not give the option to place this Button. I'm using v2 of Filament.
Regarding `->reactive()`, it is a rule so that when someone types in one of the fields, the others disappear.